# Descarga fichero jsf 2.2 primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estoy intentado hacer uso del componente `p:fileDownload` de primefaces.

```
<p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s">
       <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadView.file}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

ManageBean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class FileDownloadView {

    private StreamedContent file;

    public FileDownloadView() {        
        InputStream stream = ((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\Yo\\Desktop\\excel.xlsx");
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "docu.xlsx");
    }

    public StreamedContent getFile() {
        return file;
    }
}
```

El problema está en la linea `InputStream stream...` Lo he depurado y me sale `null`. También he probado como se especifica en `primefaces.org`:

```
InputStream stream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\yo\\Excel.xlsx");
```

¿Sabeis cual  puede ser el motivo?

Comment: ¿Has leido la documentación? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

Comment: @SJuan76 si dice que si es null, el recurso no existe. Pero es un fichero que tengo en mi máquina pero no lee.

Comment: @SJuan76 He encotrado una solución: InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\yo\\Excel.xlsx"); Así si funciona.

Comment: La cuestión es que un "recurso" no es un fichero, y el path que pones no es válido para encontrar recursos: `The path must be specified according to the rules given in getResource` -> `The path must begin with a / and is interpreted as relative to the current context root, or relative to the /META-INF/resources directory of a JAR file inside the web application's /WEB-INF/lib directory. This method will first search the document root of the web application for the requested resource, before searching any of the JAR files inside /WEB-INF/lib.`

Comment: @SJuan76 ¿Entonces el `getResourceAsStream` no vale para descargar fichero que estén fuera del proyecto?